# Why angular not return the url after I hit refresh?

Tags: angular

I have in the app component router outlet.

The shell module is lazy loaded. inside shell module I have shell component with router-outlet which lazy load the dashboard component from dashboard module.

For some reason when I navigate by the url or refresh the page, angular doesn't return the dashboard url.

It's works when I use routerLink on clicking the button.

What can be the reason? and how make it work?

[codesandbox.IO](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-paper-d0d34?file=/src/app/app.module.ts)

app.module:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    loadChildren: () => import("./shell.module").then((m) => m.ShellModule)
  }
];
imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
```

shell.module:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "dashboard",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./dashboard.module").then((m) => m.DashboardModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

dashboard.module:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a dashboard path as a child, which means that you need to navigate to `/dashboard` in order to fetch the module and show the `DashboardModule`, which inlcudes the `DashboardComponent`.

If you need to show the `DashboardComponent` directly, then you need to remove the "dashboad" from the path in the `ShellModule`

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: ShellComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./dashboard.module").then((m) => m.DashboardModule)
      }
    ]
  }
];
```